# Annotation processing with gradle nothing in factorypath on eclipse

Tags: gradle, annotation-processing

i'm switching from maven to gradle.

Here is what i used to have in my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>./test</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>rockpalm.it</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ic2-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

My build.gradle looks like :

```
plugins {
  id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"
  id 'net.ltgt.apt-eclipse' version '0.15' 
}
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "rockpalm.it:ic2-annotation-processor:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
ext { 
    eclipseAptFolder = '.apt_generated'
    eclipseSettingsDir = file('.settings')
}

eclipse {
    jdt.file.withProperties { 
        it['org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations'] = 'enabled'
    }
}

tasks.eclipseJdt {
    doFirst {
        def aptPrefs = file("${eclipseSettingsDir}/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs")
        aptPrefs.parentFile.mkdirs()

        aptPrefs.text = """\
    eclipse.preferences.version=1
    org.eclipse.jdt.apt.aptEnabled=true
    org.eclipse.jdt.apt.genSrcDir=${eclipseAptFolder}
    org.eclipse.jdt.apt.reconcileEnabled=true
    """.stripIndent()

        file('.factorypath').withWriter {
            new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(it).'factorypath' {
                project.configurations.annotationProcessor.each { dep->
                    factorypathentry(
                        kind:'EXTJAR',
                        id:dep.absolutePath,
                        enabled:true,
                        runInBatchMode:false
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use Gradle > Refresh gradle project it does not configure the .factorypath of eclipse with my annotation processor, it enables it but without setting the actual processor on the processor list.

When I run the gradle build I can actually see my generated code in build/generated/source/apt/main/...my packages/classes but since it's not enabled in eclipse I have nothing in .apt_generated folder.

**EDIT**
I got gradle to build the factorypath correctly with the `tasks.eclipseJdt` part of the build.gradle but eclipse doesn't seem to build anything in the .apt_generated still. How can I debug eclipse gradle build to see what's happening ?

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. After executing `gradle eclipse` - "Annotation Processing" is activated in eclipse, "Factory Path" is also set correctly. Eclipse does not generate anything. gradle build is working from the console. Did you find a work around?

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't need the `eclipse` configuration closure from the plugin example, just use:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.15'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-eclipse' version '0.15' 
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'rockpalm.it:ic2-annotation-processor:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Execute `gradle eclipse` to setup the factory path and refresh the project in Eclipse.

Comment: It still doesn't compile anything in .apt_generated

Comment: Does the factory path file exist? Are you sure your annotation processor works? Is the dependency correct?

Comment: I'm sure it works since it's good with maven and it's good with a gradlew build, the .factory exists, but contains only `<factorypathentry kind="PLUGIN" id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.annotations.core" enabled="false" runInBatchMode="false"/>` the dependency therefore is correct since its works good with maven